# Powering 3 micro stepping pumps simultaneously

Tags: controller, stepper, motordriver

I am currently working on a project that requires me to use 3 micro stepping motors that act as a peristaltic pump. I have no access to the data sheet, but the company we purchased them from has provided the seemingly crucial information which I will include below. The microcontroller is an ESP32 dev kit c4, and I am using 3 STSPIN220 breakout module from Pololu for the drivers.

The goal of the project is to control 3 pumps simultaneously, I am currently using a modification of the AccelStepper Library, that I have created for readability, in order to accomplish this task. The software is functional, however I am having trouble with the circuit design.

Currently, I can run all three motors at once at different rates. They will typically not run right away, and I have to tune all 3 potentiometers in order for it to work. I then change the rates at which the motors are moving, and then all the potentiometers have to be tuned again! After much head banging, I realized that tuning the controller for motor 1 may end up effecting motor 1, or it will only cause changes in motor 2 or even motor 3. This lead me to testing out the hardware/code on a single motor. The result is perfect. I get my potentiometer to be set to the appropriate VRef for my desired current, and boom, I do not have to change it again. I can consistently modify the RPM of the motor, and no issues. This leads me to believe it is something to do with the circuit design which I am not fully understanding. I have included two schematics, one is a breakdown of just the 3 driver boards, esp32, and how they receive their power. The other one(which has had some modifications on the pin inputs to the driver boards) is the schematic of the full project. It contains a few more parts that I do not think play a role in the current issue, but I have included it just incase. Any and all suggestion help! Thanks in advance!

I also apologize if this isn't the right category for this topic. Motors and power seemed fitting, though this isn't a high powered system what so ever.

Stepper Motor Specs:

Inductance Rating: 2.2mH (REF. At 25C 1KHz,1.0Vrms (Each phase))
Rated Voltage: 2.6VDC
Rated Current: around 200mA at 2.6VDC
Type: 2-2 Phase exciting, bi-polar stepper motor
Step angle: 0.349880 degrees
Speed reduction ratio: 1:51.4462
Pump can rotate: CW or CCW, but make sure the pump is completely
stopped for 2-3 sec before changing the rotation direction.
Resistance: 21 ohms +/-5% (at 25C)
Max starting pulse rate: 800pps/min (constant voltage, no load)
Max constant pulse rate: 1000pps/min (same as above)

Here is a link to a google drive folder containing the schematics:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LPgtmt0KvdQsxpeSnbz-tUwwSe8YI1Tz?usp=share_link

What I have tried so far:

- I have tried dc barrel jack power supplies (common 12v 2A), as well as bench power supply
- I have tried bypassing the linear voltage regulators and supplying upwards of 12v directly to the STSPIN220 breakoutboards (To the Vmot and GND line)